# Firebase/DrawerLayout - Logged out for no reason?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I am working on a DrawerLayout, and when I click one of the items to go to a Profile page, it logs me out (I can notice this because I get a NullPointer error for the UserAuth [even though I was authed before clicking this]

Note: I didn't notice this until I tried to modularize my code by adding "initialize" methods and such.

This is the code for the items in the drawerlayout:

```
private void setupDrawerLayout() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //If Clicked...then get item and go to associated page
                switch(menuItem.getTitle().toString())
                {
                    case "Profile":
                        Log.i("Profile", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    /*case "Share":
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    case "Settings":
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class)); */
                    case "Logout":
                        Log.i("Logout", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        //startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
                }
        });
    }
```

For some reason even though I'm clicking the "Profile" item, it goes to both the Case for that, AND for "Logout" as can be seen by the Log statements:

```
I/Profile: Profile
I/Logout: Profile
```

And then this leads to the Error:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock/com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
                         at com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock.Activities.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:70)
```

ProfileActivity.java (is the activity I am trying to get to by clicking on the ITEM in the menu). It refers to this line, but really the error is coming from HomeActivity as I understand it... ) :

```
 currentUserString = currentUser.getUid().toString();
```

HomeActivity.java:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageView menu, closeDrawer;
    RelativeLayout navHeader;

    //Profile Stuff
    DatabaseReference employeesRefPhoto, employeesRefFname, employeesRefLname;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    String photoUrl;
    ImageView profilePhoto;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    String currentUserString;
    TextView nameTV, lnameTV;
    TextView businessesTV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);

        /////////////////////////
        //METHODS
        //initViews();
        //setupDrawerLayout();
        //footerOnClick();
        //////////////////////////

        menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(final View view) {
                                            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                                    }
                                });

        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        currentUserString = currentUser.getUid().toString();

        setupDrawerLayout();

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163579/null-pointer-exception-on-navigation-header-initialized-variables
        navHeader=(RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
        navigationView.addHeaderView(navHeader); //This seems to add a SECOND "X" image

        nameTV = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.employeeFname);
        lnameTV = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.employeeLname);

        closeDrawer = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.closedrawer);
        profilePhoto = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.profilephoto);
        businessesTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.businesses);

         closeDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //INFORMATION FOR MENU/////////////////////
        //PROFILE PHOTO
        //currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //currentUserString = currentUser.getUid().toString();

        setupDrawerLayout();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        employeesRefPhoto = database.getReference("Employees").child(currentUserString).child("photoDownloadUrl");
        employeesRefPhoto.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("onDataChange","Inside");

                try {
                    photoUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.i("photoUrl", photoUrl);
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(photoUrl).into(profilePhoto);
                    profilePhoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.i("Null", e.toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("Cancelled",databaseError.toString());
            }
        });

        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        //GET NAME//////////////////////////////////
        //FIRST NAME
        employeesRefFname = database.getReference("Employees").child(currentUserString).child("firstName");
        employeesRefFname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    Log.i("firstname", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    nameTV.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {  Log.i("FNull?", e.toString());     }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {   Log.d("Cancelled",databaseError.toString());     }
        });

        //LAST NAME
        employeesRefLname = database.getReference("Employees").child(currentUserString).child("lastName");
        employeesRefLname.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    Log.i("lastname", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                    lnameTV.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {  Log.i("LNull?", e.toString());     }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {   Log.d("Cancelled",databaseError.toString());     }
        });

        //footerOnClick();
        footerOnClick();



    } //END OF ONCREATE

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    //INITIALIZE VIEWS
    private void initViews(){
        navHeader=(RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);

        nameTV = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.employeeFname);
        lnameTV = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.employeeLname);

        menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        closeDrawer = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.closedrawer);
        profilePhoto = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.profilephoto);
        businessesTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.businesses);
    }

    //INTENTS FOR THE FOOTER OF THE SCREEN
    private void footerOnClick() {

        businessesTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, BusinessesActivity.class));
            }
        });

        //EMPLOYEES
        //PAYROLL REPORT
    }

    //MENU / DRAWER
    //https://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/
    private void setupDrawerLayout() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //If Clicked...then get item and go to associated page
                switch(menuItem.getTitle().toString())
                {
                    case "Profile":
                        Log.i("Profile", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    /*case "Share":
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    case "Settings":
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class)); */
                    case "Logout":
                        Log.i("Logout", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        //startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                }

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    //??????????????????????????????????????
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


} //END OF CLASS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `setupDrawerLayout()` under `onNavigationItemSelected()` you have a switch statement. 
In each case of the switch statement use `break` else all the following switch conditions may execute. Since the last case is to logout, the user might be getting signed out each time the switch statement executes.

Comment: kindly mark the answer as correct if it has led to the solution.

Comment: Interesting, it works. I would have thought since I had Intents that I wouldn't need a break but apparently I do.

Comment: This is because starting an activity does not finish the current activity on which the switch statement was running, so although there is a new activity which has started, the previous activity would continue to finish the ongoing statement unless it is destroyed.